# Python matrix give the same result as in the last record

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix

I try creating a matrix using list of list with fixed number of elements. I initialized the matrix with 0 for each cell, then iterate over all the elements and in each cell, I multiply each row and column number like this.

```
test = [[0] * (10)] * 10
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        test[i][j] = i * j
```

When I print `test`, the result is

```
[[0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45,54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9,18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63,72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81], [0, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]]
```

It looks like only the last `i` with `i=9` is calculated. What I expect is the result of row and column multiplication.
How to do this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't instantiate an empty list first, just use a list comprehension.

```py
test = [[i * j for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

With Numpy:

```py
size = np.arange(10)

test = size * size[:, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program list has been cloned to 10 times hence it is producing the last modification to the matrix.